# How does readFileSync of fs node module work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to see the code of fs node module so that I can how does this module implement this file reading functionality synchronously. I did try to search in node_modules folder. But I did not get any reference. Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: It's implemented in C. Also, node.js built-in modules are not in node_modules

Comment: You can see the implementation here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L537 . Eventually it calls fs.readSync() which will eventually call a bound C function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code:

```
fs.readFileSync = function(path, options) {
  options = getOptions(options, { flag: 'r' });
  var isUserFd = isFd(path); // file descriptor ownership
  var fd = isUserFd ? path : fs.openSync(path, options.flag || 'r', 0o666);

  // Use stats array directly to avoid creating an fs.Stats instance just for
  // our internal use.
  var size;
  if (tryStatSync(fd, isUserFd) && (statValues[1/*mode*/] & S_IFMT) === S_IFREG)
    size = statValues[8/*size*/];
  else
    size = 0;
  var pos = 0;
  var buffer; // single buffer with file data
  var buffers; // list for when size is unknown

  if (size === 0) {
    buffers = [];
  } else {
    buffer = tryCreateBuffer(size, fd, isUserFd);
  }

  var bytesRead;

  if (size !== 0) {
    do {
      bytesRead = tryReadSync(fd, isUserFd, buffer, pos, size - pos);
      pos += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead !== 0 && pos < size);
  } else {
    do {
      // the kernel lies about many files.
      // Go ahead and try to read some bytes.
      buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8192);
      bytesRead = tryReadSync(fd, isUserFd, buffer, 0, 8192);
      if (bytesRead !== 0) {
        buffers.push(buffer.slice(0, bytesRead));
      }
      pos += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead !== 0);
  }

  if (!isUserFd)
    fs.closeSync(fd);

  if (size === 0) {
    // data was collected into the buffers list.
    buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers, pos);
  } else if (pos < size) {
    buffer = buffer.slice(0, pos);
  }

  if (options.encoding) buffer = buffer.toString(options.encoding);
  return buffer;
};
```

You can find the full file (to understand the context) in

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js